# How to go previous page of current page , while clicking  browser back button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

There is  three pages  say step1.php, progress.php, step2.php

the flow is step1-> progress-> step2

So once we reach at step2 and press browser back button, it  will go to **progress** page.

I wants it should go to step1, while clicking the back button of browser,on step2

Comment: Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+history

Comment: No,i don't know a solution, how can i reach from step2->step1 by skipping progress page.While clicking back button of browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is check in **progress** page if it's from step1. If yes, ok, otherwise redirect the user to step1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things and breaking the back button from its default behavior is not one of them.

Pass reference for page "step1" along the path via querystring or form.

or 
from client side scripting access the window.history object.

for instance in JavaScript:

```
window.history.go(-2) //will take you back two pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser's BACK and FORWARD buttons will simply go to the URLs that were on display in the browser.  The buttons don't care about content, and you can't reliably affect their behaviour with Javascript.

One workaround is to attach javascript to jump multiple hops through your window.history object.  But as I say, *this is inconsistent*, because some browsers may disable this, and some may hit your site with JS disabled entirely.

I suggest you look at using modal dialog for your progress indicator, so that the top-level URL is the stepN.php script alone.  That still requires PHP, but it's less likely to cause failure.  [This kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428025/jquery-dialog-box-php-form) has been discussed here before.